# Javascript define variable one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am working on making some an 'about us' page on our company's site. I have a pic, and I am putting absolute placed speech or 'thought bubbles' above each person's head, with information. I can't share the page, as we are developing on a secure server, but I am attaching the JQuery that i am using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.readMore').toggle(function () {
        var width = $(this).width();
        var height = $(this).height();
        var increment = 200;
        $(this).parent().css("z-index", "9999").animate({
            "width": width + increment,
            "height": height + increment,
            "margin-left": -(width / 2)
        }, 300);
        $(this).html("Read less >>");
    });
});
</script>
```

I have the animation set to run pretty much the way I want it to, but the one thing that I keep getting stuck on is this. I want JQuery to capture the width and height of each div when it is clicked on (it does this. I am storing the information in two variables called width and height), and then use as the base for the animate function to set it's width and height to the original+200px (this also works fine). However, once that animation has run, I want the original width and height variables to stay the same as they were before the animation, so that I can revert the div height and width to the original for that particular div. 
Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, define the variables out of the `toggle` scope like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var originalWidth = $('.readMore').width(),
        originalHeight = $('.readMore').height();
    $('.readMore').toggle(function () {
        var width = $(this).width();
        var height = $(this).height();

        if (originalWidth !== width){
        //do the magic
        }

        if (originalHeight !== height){
        //do the magic
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for that. It makes sense once it's put down so clearly like that. Appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: Done. Sorry, I am pretty new to Stackoverflow, so I didn't know how to  do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare variable outside of your ready(), those variable will keep your data even outside the function. You can, for example, keep the original width and height on 2 variable outside of the ready function, and they will stay the same between each call.